# Portal 2 Trailer Music

Tags: portal-2

What is the music in the Investment Opportunity trailer?  I'm not talking about Reconstructing Science, I'm talking about the wake-up sound (the one that also plays during the movement tutorial in the game itself, and is kind of garbled and corrupted at the beginning of "The Wake-Up Call").  It's the music featured in [this trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F_Bg2Uuxh48).  I appreciate any help anyone can give to this two-year-old question of mine!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean the music that I think you mean, then it's *Santorini*, by Greek instrumentalist Yanni Hryssomallis. The original is [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3auxOlTl2MQ).

It sounds like an electronic version rather than the original in the trailer though.

Comment: I was not expecting Yanni.  Thank you!  Sorry it took so long to accept!